# How to insert an array in adjacency list with vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

In this code, I tried insert an array in adjacency list, but I cant access the 3 dimension. I need to insert a puzzle 8 like a graph to solve with some search.

I tried using vector and when I insert an array into vector it nota return each position ir puzzle.

```
int puzzle1[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int puzzle2[9] = {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
int puzzle3[9] = {1,4,7,2,5,0,8,3,6};
int puzzle4[9] = {3,2,0,1,6,5,4,8,7};

vector<int*> *adj;

adj = new vector<int*> (4);

adj[0].push_back(puzzle1);
adj[0].push_back(puzzle2);
adj[0].push_back(puzzle3);
adj[0].push_back(puzzle4);

cout<<adj[0][0][3];
```

I need that allocate the pointer because I Will use this solution in a class Graph, that Will have this adjacency list and I Will access to expand the graph.

Comment: You are mixing raw arrays, `vector`s, and `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct the vector:

```
adj = new vector<int*> (4);
```

it has four elements. Four uninitialized `int*` values. When you add an element to the vector:

```
adj[0].push_back(puzzle1);
```

You add it to the back. The vector now has *five* elements, and the first four are still uninitialized. When you dereference the first one:

```
cout<<adj[0][0][3];
```

you get undefined behavior.

You could have discovered this by playing with `vector<int>` a little more before attempting `vector<int[]>*`.